# `List` or `array`datastructer to store pick values from array c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, optimization, data-structures

I am finding all pick from `double` array so which data structure should efficient  `List` or `Array` to store result?
I want to it to efficient by running not by memory.

```
double[] n = new double[]{2,1,6,5,3,8,1};  # could be n number of elements
```

If i choice

> **Array**:
>   I can declare first `result` array to store pick elements as total size of `n` and then after finding pick i will `resize` it.
>
> ---
>
> **List**:
>   Or i can use list but my concern is "List will add extra memory each time when list going to full" so it would be cost run time.

So Should i use `list` or `array` because here i know what would be "max size" of `result` ?

Comment: double[] not double()....

Comment: Can't you use Linked List? This way you can have constant time for Add() and Remove(). It comes of course with the cost of O(n) complexity for finding an element.

Comment: @Frenchy sorry did not get your question

Comment: Chose what fits your needs. Memory shouldn´t be your first concern here, in particluar as the lists memory overhead shouldn´t be that huge. If you want to iterate your collection, chose `IEnumerable`, if you need index-based take array or list. If you want to add/remove items, chose list.

Comment: You worry unnecessarily. `List` does not "add extra memory each time." `List` grows by doubling. The `Count` property tells you how many items are in the list, and `Capacity` tells you how many it can hold. The amortized cost of adding to a `List` is O(1). If you're worried about the allocation time and have an idea of how many items the list will hold, you can pre-allocate the list by passing a capacity parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data will increase in size dynamically, you should almost certainly prefer a list to an array. The list uses an array internally and will automatically create a new, larger array whenever it is full. By default the capacity is doubled each time the list is full, but you can control this yourself by setting `list.Capacity`. For most cases the default growing strategy should be fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the [initial capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_) when creating the list. If you do this the difference is minimal. Use whatever you prefer.

You should consider the range of inputs you expect. If you expect to store a few megabytes it probably does not matter much. If it is gigabytes then overhead and fragmenting may become important. If it is terabytes then you will need to consider streaming data from secondary storage or work on separate chunks of data at a time.